# Div not floating

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to arrange a site's footer.

The problem seems to be with the float statement. `.logo` should align left, but it's aligned right.

This is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dulkre</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- HTML Snippet -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <header>
            <img src="./img/logo.png" id="logo" />

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Quienes Somos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Productos</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Endulzantes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Life con sucralosa</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Cl&aacute;sico</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Fructofibra</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Mate</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Gourmet</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Recetas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Bienestar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section id="wrapper">
            <article id="slider"></article>

            <article id="cuerpo"></article>
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div id="pie">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./img/logo.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="copy"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the css

```
footer{ height: 115px; width:100%; background: #aad361; }
footer #pie { width:960px; margin:0 auto; height:115px; }
footer #pie .logo { width:168px; float:left; display: block; }

footer #pie .copy { margin-left: 198px; height:115px; display: block; width:762px; }
```

Any ideas of what am i doing wrong?

---

Here's a url where you can see all code

http://dulkre.com.ar/newsite/

Comment: can you recreate this issue in a fiddle?

Comment: your code is working here

Comment: I found the same as @MrBearandBeer, code seems to be working here

Comment: maybe it has something in the rest of your code that are influencing the element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are floating the div element, when you should float the img.

This is the right code:

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div id="pie">
      <img class="logo" class="img" src="./img/logo.png" />
    </div>
</footer>
```

And the CSS:

```
footer { 
    height: 115px;
    width:100%; 
    background: #aad361; 
}

footer #pie {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:115px; 
}

footer #pie .logo { 
    width:168px; 
    float: left; 
}
```

If you want use your code and achieve the same result, just use:

```
.footer #pie .logo img {
     width:168px; 
     float: left; 
}
```

Comment: The result sohuld be the same. .logo contains the image